# Migrate plain text passwords to Bcrypt using CakePHP 3.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, cakephp, bcrypt

I'm building a CakePHP 3.4 application with an user authentication form which uses the DefaultPasswordHasher API to validate user login data (username and password).

I would like to migrate an existing SQL Server database which stores users passwords in plain text (i know, the horror!) to a new MySQL database specifically created for this new application that i'm building.

As far as i understand, DefaultPasswordHasher uses bcrypt to store passwords in a database.

How can i migrate all the old passwords in plain text from the existing database to my new database which stores passwords using the DefaultPasswordHasher API from CakePHP? What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP comes with a PasswordHasher that will transparently migrate them.

> CakePHP provides a clean way to migrate your users’ passwords from one algorithm to another, this is achieved through the FallbackPasswordHasher class. Assuming you are migrating your app from CakePHP 2.x which uses sha1 password hashes, you can configure the AuthComponent as follows:

See the section [Changing Hashing Algorithms](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#changing-hashing-algorithms).

Or if you want to conver them all at once instantiate a password hasher using the [password hasherfactory](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Auth.PasswordHasherFactory.html) and read all records in chunks and iterate over them in a while loop, hash them with your hasher object and save them. This can be done via a shell or in a migration.